# Firefox or Chrome Auto Hide UI

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, gui

I want to automatically hide the firefox ui until I mouse hover the top of my browser window without having to full screen.

I love the windows task bar auto hide feature and hate that I cant find a browser where I can seemingly easily set this up.

Does anyone know how to realize this with Chrome or Firefox browsers? There seems to be no extensions for it I can find.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not aware of an add-in to do it, but [this](https://www.abettergeek.com/software/fixing-firefox-quantum-auto-hiding-toolbars/) might work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I've got something that works, based on the classic userChrome.css technique that people used to use all the time on older versions of Firefox, and still works today if you enable it in about:config. It's based on a Gist link found on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4biepx/any_alternative_to_toolbar_autohide/) and adapted to make it work on maximized windows.

Follow [this guide on how to set up your userChrome](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html)...

- Adding the chrome directory in the right place in your profile folder
- Making the file
- Setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` `about:config` so Firefox will use it when loaded.

Put the following code into your userChrome.css:

```
  #navigator-toolbox {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #navigator-toolbox:hover {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: show;
  }
```

Screenshots:

[image: Window without hover]

[image: Window with hover]