# How to customize the UI of google chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser

Default view of `VIVALDI` browser:

[image]

Now when you hit ctrl+f11, it hides all the UI (search bar, buttons, caption, etc), maintaining the current browser width/height.

[image]

Is possible to achieve ***this*** look on chrome? i mean, hide everything of the UI, similar to what you achieve when you go to fullscreen.

The problem of going fullscreen is that it changes the dimension of the browser which i would like to avoid.

I have found these topics, but its for firefox only:
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4biepx/any_alternative_to_toolbar_autohide/

[Firefox or Chrome Auto Hide UI](https://superuser.com/questions/1461803/firefox-or-chrome-auto-hide-ui)

Comment: What do you mean by "it changes the dimension of the browser"?

Comment: @gronostaj The browser is resized her width/height is changed to your desktop width/height

Comment: If it doesn't adjust, what would you want to see in the extra area? Black?

Comment: I want to see anything, im not talking about the fullscreen option...

Answer (score 0):

To hide UI you can use **Open-as-popup** extenstion which will re-open current tab as a pop-up. Brillian, it doesn't hide the app bar but it's as close as you can get to hide UI from within Chrome.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-as-popup/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc/related